# Jssor combine video gallery with slideshow

Tags: jquery, jssor

I am trying to apply slideshow transition effect to video gallery, although it works, it doesn't look good. See this link: http://usbsc.com/jssorwsk/demos-jquery/image-slider-2.source.html

When transit from 1st slide(video player) to the 2nd slide(image), the image will show up at the very first moment, and then the video player shows up again, only after this the transition starts.

Besides, it seems the transion effect occurs only when the slideshows autoplay, when navigating the slideshows by clicking the arrows or the thumbnails, the slideshow will only simply slide. How can I make the transition effect also take place when clicking arrows?

By the way, thanks for developing this great project, and amazingly, it is totally free. I have clicked the advertisements on your site, please let me know how can I donate to this project.

Answer (score 0):

Video is very  heavy element in slider, it's not recommended to enable slideshow on a video slider.

For now, on demand navigation request (click on bullet/arrow/thumbnail) will lead sliding left<->right effect. I will improve this feature later.

Thanks for your interest and support, I am working on an online generation tool for jssor slider, I will publish it as value added service a few months later.
I am going to make money with it (maybe $8/year membership fee). No need to donate this project then.
I am appreciated that you clicked AD on our site, but please DO NOT click on any AD intentionally.

Thanks again for your feedback! I will keep improving jssor slider. Kind Regards.